# Runtime environment variable for react app

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline, create-react-app

We have three environments `Dev`, `Staging` and `Prod`. Create-react-app build is quite suitable for all the three environments but the only things change during the build is the environment variable for API endpoint.

We are using the Jenkins pipeline for the build process and putting the output in `S3 Bucket`, the only problem with that process is that we have to make a separate build for every environment although everything is same except that API environment variable. It takes a significant amount of time.

So I possible solution is to move from compiled environment variable to runtime environment. I came across [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/578#issuecomment-277843310). But I don't know how to do it in practical being newbie to `Jenkins` and `AWS`

Our folder structure looks like this

```
Project
|---mocks
|---static
|---index.html
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">

    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React APP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See docs https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Again that will run during build process. Mean I have run a build for every environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I am writing the way we have fixed this. In `Jenkinfile` file which is placed inside our project repo. We have made following changes for every environment.

Before every stage we simply re-writing the `env.js` with respective file.

```
 stage('Push to Dev') {
       ...
       steps {
         .....
           sh 'cp ./config/dev.js ./build/env.js'
            .....
       }
    }
```